# Bootstrap responsive design issues on iOS7

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 css/js files for my html pages and facing following 2 problems:

1. Html page design (font style, height/width of pictures) is fine on iOS 6 devices but its not working on iOS 7 devices. On iOS7, I even can not read text and all contents are very small. How can I fix this iOS 7 problem using Bootstrap 3 css/js files?
2. I am trying to open same html page on Windows Mobile (Lumia 925) and all contents are not fit to screen. It's not 100% perfect.

Any suggestion or solution?

Comment: In future provide your code somewhere so we can reproduce the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this metatag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,maximum-scale=1.0" />
```